# Using different api url from .env based on environment in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use different api url for stage(development) and production environment I have defined the url in my nuxt.config.js like this

```
import redirectSSL from "redirect-ssl";

const isProdEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const DEV_API_URL =  "https://example-stage.herokuapp.com/v1/";
const PROD_API_URL = "https://example.herokuapp.com/v1/";
const API_URL = isProdEnv ? PROD_API_URL : DEV_API_URL;

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  ssr: true,
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  app: {
    head: {
      title: "project",
      meta: [
        {
          charset: "utf-8",
        },
        {
          name: "viewport",
          content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
        },
        {
          "http-equiv": "X-UA-Compatible",
          content: "IE=edge",
        },
      ],
      link: [
        {
          href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&display=swap",
          rel: "stylesheet",
        },
        {
          href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap",
          rel: "stylesheet",
        },
        {
          href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp",
          rel: "stylesheet",
        },
      ],
      script: [],
    },
  },
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/index.scss";',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  css: ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css"],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiURL: API_URL || "https://example.herokuapp.com/v1/",
    },
  },
  modules: [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    // "floating-vue/nuxt"
  ],
  serverMiddleware: [
    redirectSSL.create({
      enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    }),
  ],

  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      console.log(config);
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(csv|xlsx|xls)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: `files/[name].[ext]`,
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
```

when I run this locally it's working fine I launched local production server with `node .output/server/index.mjs` and it's getting the API URLs fine but when I deploy this in Heroku it's not getting the API_URL correctly I have set the NODE_ENV in heroku to satage for the stage build but it always reads the production URL because the fallback is the production URL in the runtime config can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to define staging / production API URLs in nuxt.config.js file. You should have something like API_BASE_URL variable in the .env file. When building for production with `npm run build` and/or `npm run generate` simply update your .env file before building and your app should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing the variable name in .env file to  `NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE` and changing the runtimeConfig to this

```
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase:
        process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE
       
    },
  },
```

Based on the documentation here https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#environment-variables